# Is it possible for nextAll() to only select a certain number of elements instead of all the elements that follow?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to create a drop own list.

```
<dl>
<dt>Option 1</dt>
<dd><a href="#" /></dd>//a
<dd><a href="#" /></dd>//b
<dd><a href="#" /></dd>//c
<dt>Option 2</dt>
<dd><a href="#" /></dd>//1
<dd><a href="#" /></dd>//2
<dd><a href="#" /></dd>//3
</dl>
```

My jquery:

```
<script>
$('dd').hide();
$(document).ready(function(){
$('dt').bind('click', function(){
$(this).toggleClass('open').nextAll('dd').slideToggle(2000);
});
});
</script>
```

What I would like is that when the user click on Option 1 (dt), only a, b, and c is revealed. Click on Option 2 (dt), only 1, 2, and 3 is revealed. Currently what is happening is that all the dd are being revealed( a, b, c and 1, 2, 3). I removed the all from the nextAll() and only a and 1 is being revealed. Is there a way to reveal only the  information that follows the dt without revealing all dd?

Comment: you are closing your dl with dt??

Comment: That was an error. Closing tag is dl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) to match all the following sibling elements until the next `<dt>`:

```
$("dt").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("open").nextUntil("dt").slideToggle(2000);
});
```